# Application crash when calling container.get() in abstract class's constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, inversifyjs

I'm currently trying to implement a base class which has multiple properties. All but one property are being injected via the constructor using InversifyJS's @Inject tag. I'm also getting an instance via the container.Get() function in the constructor. When I run my application everything is fine, but when the application recieves a request, the app crashes without an error.

[image]

**Base class**

```
/**
 * Base class for all intent logic
 */
@injectable()
export default abstract class IntentBase implements IIntent {
  protected logger: ILogger;
  protected responseService: IResponseService;
  protected contextService: IContextService;
  protected fallbackIntent: IIntent;
  protected responseBuilder: IResponseBuilder;

  /**
   * Constructor
   * @param logger logger
   * @param responseService response service
   * @param contextService context service
   */
  constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.WinstonLogger) logger: ILogger,
    @inject(TYPES.ResponseService) responseService: IResponseService,
    @inject(TYPES.ContextService) contextService: IContextService,
    @inject(TYPES.ResponseBuilder) responseBuilder: IResponseBuilder,
  ) {
    this.logger = logger;
    this.responseService = responseService;
    this.contextService = contextService;
    this.responseBuilder = responseBuilder;
    this.fallbackIntent = container.get(TYPES.DefaultFallbackIntent); // <-- container.Get() line
  }

  /**
   * Override the standard fallback logic for an intent.
   * @param fallback fallback to set
   */
  setFallback(fallback: IIntent): void {
    this.fallbackIntent = fallback;
  }
```

When I uncomment the container.get(TYPES.DefaultFallbackIntent) line, my application can recieve requests like normally and it doesn't crash. The reason why I am trying this injection setup is because I'd like to set a default behavior for each child class in the constructor.

Does anyone have an explaination to why I cannot seem to inject this class? 
Thanks in advance

**Update**

**inversify.config.ts**

```
import DefaultFallbackIntent from "./src/bot/intents/fallbacks/defaultFallbackIntent";
import TextResponseRepository from "./src/repositories/textResponseRepository";
import SsmlResponseRepsitory from "./src/repositories/ssmlResponseRepository";
import ContextService from "./src/services/contextService";
import GoogleResponseBuilder from "./src/builders/googleResponseBuilder";

const container = new Container();

container.bind<IGoogleAssistantController>(TYPES.GoogleController).to(GoogleAssistantController);
container.bind<IResponseService>(TYPES.ResponseService).to(ResponseSerivce);
container.bind<IContextService>(TYPES.ContextService).to(ContextService);
container.bind<IResponseRepository>(TYPES.TextResponseRepository).to(TextResponseRepository);
container.bind<IResponseRepository>(TYPES.SsmlResponseRepository).to(SsmlResponseRepsitory);
container.bind<ILogger>(TYPES.WinstonLogger).to(WinstonLogger);

container.bind<IIntent>(TYPES.WelcomeIntent).to(WelcomeIntent);
container.bind<IIntent>(TYPES.DefaultFallbackIntent).to(DefaultFallbackIntent);
container.bind<IResponseBuilder>(TYPES.ResponseBuilder).to(GoogleResponseBuilder);

export { container };
```

**Default fallback intent**

```
/**
 * Default fallback intent class
 */
@injectable()
export default class DefaultFallbackIntent extends IntentBase {
  invoke(conv: DialogflowConversation): DialogflowConversation {
    const response = this.responseService.getResponse("defaultFallback");
    return conv.ask(response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `container.get(<Type>)` to work, `<Type>` must be [bound](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS#step-3-create-and-configure-a-container) to the container at some point. In your composition root (where you set up your container) you can create this binding:

```
const container = new Container();
container.bind<IIntent>(TYPES.DefaultFallbackIntent)).to(<TheDefaultFallbackIntentClass>);
```

EDIT:

From the discussion in the comments it seems that `DefaultFallbackIntent` inherting from `IntentBase` is the problem, because at the time `DefaultFallbackIntent` gets instantiated (through binding it), there doesn't exist such an instance in the container when the base constructor is executed.

A workaround would be to not inherit from `IntentBase` and just implement the interface and set the required fields in this class as well:

```
/**
 * Default fallback intent class
 */
@injectable()
export default class DefaultFallbackIntent implements IIntent {
protected logger: ILogger;
  private responseService: IResponseService;
  private contextService: IContextService;
  private fallbackIntent: IIntent;
  private responseBuilder: IResponseBuilder;

  invoke(conv: DialogflowConversation): DialogflowConversation {
    const response = this.responseService.getResponse("defaultFallback");
    return conv.ask(response);
  }
}
```

However, a better solution would be two create another super class which contains all the required fields both the default fallback intent and others have in order to reduce duplicated code.

Comment: This has been setup, I've added my container setup to the question.

Comment: Hm, can you try to put `container.bind<IIntent>(TYPES.DefaultFallbackIntent).to(DefaultFallbackIntent);` before `container.bind<IIntent>(TYPES.WelcomeIntent).to(WelcomeIntent);` ?

Comment: If that does not help add the code for `DefaultFallbackIntent` please.

Comment: Switching the bindings didn't work, I've added the default welcome intent implementation. Could it be an issue with both classes inheriting from IntentBase?

Comment: Yep - I think `DefaultFallbackIntent` inherting from `IntentBase` is the problem, because at the time `DefaultFallbackIntent` gets instantiated (through binding it), there doesn't exist such an instance in the container when the base constructor is executed. As a test you could try to not inherit from `IntentBase` in `DefaultFallbackIntent`.

Comment: I went with a third approach. I set ```this.fallbackIntent``` in ```IntentBase``` to undefined in the constructor. Then right after that I called a protected function called ```initializeFallback()```. This sets ```this.fallbackintent``` to fallback intent, but in the fallbackintent class I overrode it to set it to undefined since a fallback doesnt need another fallback. This saved alot of duplicate code.

Comment: Great, that sounds even better :)